# Deploying .settings - Error: Not available for deploy for this organisation

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

I am trying to deploy some .settings files to an org. The org is a sandbox of where the original metadata was pulled from.

This is the following error I am receiving, but it's not very descriptive.

```
Component Failures:
1.  settings/MarketingAction.settings -- Error: Not available for deploy for this organization
2.  settings/PersonList.settings -- Error: Not available for deploy for this organization
3.  settings/LiveAgent.settings -- Error: Not available for deploy for this organization
4.  settings/Territory2.settings -- Error: Not available for deploy for this organization
5.  settings/PersonalJourney.settings -- Error: Not available for deploy for this organization
```

I cannot seem to find any documentation for this, both orgs and the package.xml are using version 35 of the metadata API. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think the api has been fully updated yet. I see these kinds of errors in eclipse all the time where it's not able to retrieve all of the metadata using API 35 when I enter a new org. Try using an earlier API and see if that doesn't solve your problem (assuming your data is supported under an earlier api).

Answer (score 1):

This can occur if the user doing the deployment does not have the appropriate permissions (at a minimum "API Enabled" and "Modify All Data"), or perhaps if there's a version mis-match between the two orgs you're deploying between.

Comment: As an example, I've seen this with ChatterAnswers.settings as the feature was available on v36 and is not in v37. Trying to deploy it on the v37 org gave such an error.